# Should I send a follow-up email or call again (to potential PhD supervisor)?

Tags: phd, graduate-school, supervision

Sunday: I sent an email to a potential PhD supervisor.

Sunday 4pm: he responded asking me to call him tomorrow .

Monday 11am: I responded yes and asked if there's a preferred time.

Tuesday 1am: he emailed me back asking for my number and said he will try calling me on Tuesday.

Tuesday 8am: I responded with my cell and said there are two hours when I wouldn't be available but otherwise i would be happy to chat anytime.

Tuesday 5pm: still no call. So I sent an email to say I'm available rest of today and tomorrow.

I realized now that when he asked me to call him tomorrow on Sunday, I responded in email on Monday to ask for a time instead of calling on Monday... he was kind to have responded on Tuesday and said he will try calling me. But I still have not heard from him.

Should I email or call him today?

Comment: Try both? Tag, you're it.

Comment: Do you have his number? Either way, the ball is in his court, I'd give him another day or two.

Answer (score 1):

I think it would be better to wait till the end of Wednesday, and then send a follow up email. It could be that he forgot to call or may be quite busy, given the (small) delay in his previous response. For the same reason, calling directly may not be a good idea.

In addition, do check that you did not miss any call or were unreachable at some point during the day. If so, you could mail immediately, apologize, and request to reschedule.

For future reference, it would have been better if you had mentioned your time constraints for the next several days and included your phone number in your first email that you sent on Monday. This would have made the scheduling much easier and the rest of the emails and the confusion after could have been potentially avoided.